# startssl, nginx не работает https, что я делаю неправильно?

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl, https, openssl

Как я переехал на https
1. Зарегистрировался на startssl.com, прошел проверку домена
 2. Зашел Мастер Сертификата, тыкнул DV SSL Certificate,вписал домен и поддомены.
 3. Тыкнул генерировать самостоятельно, скачал и открыл StartComTool.exe, нажал generate CSR. Сохранил ключ.
 4. На сайте ввел полученный CSR. Тыкнул кнопку передать. Тыкнул лист сертификата
 5. Тыкнул получить и скачалось. Закинул на сервер ключ из пункта 3 и CSR из архива который только что получил из папки nginxserver.
 6. Исправил рабочий конфиг nginx на следующее и он стал не рабочий:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ***;
    location / {
        root /usr/html/***;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
 return 301 https://***$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 433 ssl;
   server_name ***;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nginx/***.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/***.key;

    location / {
        root /usr/html/***;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

При попытки зайти пишет ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45405 2. предпоследняя строка имеет какой-то смысл? 3. configtest проходит удачно? 4. ошибок в логах нет?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 1. Если и так я бы получал предупреждение. 2.Без предпоследней строки то же самое, особого смысла она не несет. Да и сломать она не чего не может, она говорит что бы сервер возвращал ответ через https, что то вроде этого... 3.configtest проходит на ура и все работает кроме этого сайта. 4.В логи ошибки не пишутся.

Comment: > Закинул на сервер ключ из пункта 3 и CSR из архива...


А для работы HTTPS на веб-сервере не нужен CSR.

Comment: @AntonioK как я понял из мануалов нужно еще скачать сертификат Class 1 Intermediate Server CA, Объединить его с  сертификатом что пришел в один файл cat ***.crt sub.class1.server.ca.pem > ***.pem или этого делать не нужно?

Comment: `nginx -t` в консоли скажет вам, на какой строчке затыкается nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listen 443 ssl;
Номер порта 443, а не 433